# Saving state that resides in POCO/DTO using Actor Model

Tags: akka, poco, dto, orleans, actor-model

I was looking for some use cases or code samples that illustrate how state that resides inside simple DTO/POCO model classes can be saved using the Actor Model that impelemnets the business logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer for Orleans.

There are some samples showing the various parts required to persist state:

https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/tree/master/Samples/StorageProviders

Basically you create a class to store your grain state like this:

```
public class MyState : GrainState
{
  public string StringValue { get; set; }
  public int IntValue { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }
  public Guid GuidValue { get; set; }
  public IGrain1 GrainValue { get; set; }
}
```

(ok so this isn't a POCO)

Then you can create a grain which uses this class as it's state:

```
[ StorageProvider( ProviderName = "myprovider" ) ]
public class Grain1 : Grain< MyState >, IGrain1
{
  public Task Set( string stringValue, int intValue, DateTime dateTimeValue, Guid guidValue, IGrain1 grainValue )
  {
    State.StringValue = stringValue;
    State.IntValue = intValue;
    State.DateTimeValue = dateTimeValue;
    State.GuidValue = guidValue;
    State.GrainValue = grainValue;
    return WriteStateAsync();
  }
}
```

The underlying mechanism used to actually store the state is a configuration option. Out of the box its Azure Table Storage, but there are several other options, including Redis, Azure Blob Storage and SQL Server.